# Add a given scalar to every element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I wish to add a give scalar to every element of a list. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it:

```
7 + {3, 4, 5}
```

(*
{10, 11, 12}
*)